# can't see my published chrome extension in chrome's Web Store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

i've published a new chrome extension to the google chrome's web store, to my company account.

- we already have few extensions there.
- the extension's upload was completed successfully
- and its status is "published"
- uploaded it 3 days ago

in addition, I examined the manifest multiple times, and seems like I have all the relevant properties set there.
BUT, I can't see my extension available in the Web Store, nor find it in the search

any idea on what could be the problem ?

Comment: So what was it? I'm waiting for weeks now to get published even tho the status is published.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your app is published as **public** to be visible to everyone. I think it usually takes a week for the app to be visible. You can also reach out to the Chrome team through their [support page](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support?hl=en).